# Java threads in GUI with JMS

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jms, event-dispatch-thread

I am trying send messages with JMS in GUI Swing. When I make thread for JMS so Swing freeze, but messages are sending correct (by JBOSS logging) but it is unusable.
I need setting some parameters to Chat object from Swing.
How I can make instance of Chat class (with JMS methods) in Swing running independently on Swing and with cooperate?

Comment: I don't recommend using JMS for a chat application if that is what your building. XMPP aka jabber would be a better solution and I believe openfire comes with a swing client.

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking the Event Dispatch Thread so Swing freezes. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

As already recommended you should probably use a `SwingWorker`, which is discussed in the tutorial.

Comment: Yes, thanks, SwingWorker works fine but, I cannot handle JMS with Swing. Any solution?

Comment: I don't know what JMS is but I assume is is just an API. So that is the point of using the Swing worker, which is really just another Thread. All the JMS related code is placed in the worker. Its just Java code and not related to Swing.

Comment: Yes, I have JMS related code in worker but I need do something like:
Chat is JMS related class. In swing class: Chat c = new Chat();
c.setTextArea(textarea); c.setMessage("Message"); But object Chat has in string message still null, not "Message".

Comment: there are a few questions about Chat, JTextArea, Socket & SwingWorker, logic for JMS is very similair

Comment: its working, problem was in way between GUI and JMS, JMS didn`t recognize changing in gui.